# Can I move tagged items?

Tags: onenote

Is there a setting that will automatically move tagged items when they are complete? For example, if I have a to-do list with check boxes, once a box is checked, is there a setting that would move the item to another page? Maybe a page I have designated as "Completed items"?

Answer (score 0):

No. but you can use the Find Tags feature and tick the "Only show unchecked items" checkbox.